# Metamorphs Messing Up CSS in Ember.js Views

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using Ember.js / handlebars to loop through a collection and spit out some items that I'd like bootstrap to handle nice and responsive like.  Here is the issue:

The bootstrap-responsive css has some declrations in it like:

```
.row-fluid > [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
 }
```

and

```
.row-fluid:before, .row-fluid:after {
    display: table;
content: "";
}
```

These rules seem to target the first children.  When I loop through my collection in handlebars I end up with a bunch of metamorph code around my items:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            {{#each restaurantList}}
                {{view GS.vHomePageRestList content=this class="span6"}}
            {{/each}}
</div>
```

Here is what is produced:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <script id="metamorph-9-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
            <script id="metamorph-104-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
              <div id="ember2527" class="ember-view span6">
                My View
              </div>
            <script id="metamorph-104-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
            <script id="metamorph-105-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
              <div id="ember2574" class="ember-view span6">
                My View 2
              </div>
            <script id="metamorph-105-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
        <script id="metamorph-9-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</div>
```

So my question is this:
1.  How can I tell css to ignore script tags?
or
2.  How can I edit the css bindings so that they skip over script tags when selecting the first or first child?
or
3.  How can I structure this so that Ember uses fewer/no metamorph tags?

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/skilesare/SgwsJ/

Comment: The following seems to correct the issue.  Ember needs a way to notify me that it is finished rebinding my view.GS.vZipPage.addObserver 'restaurantList', ->
 setTimeout ->
  $("#pZipPage").find('.row-fluid').find("div:first").css('margin-left','0px')
 ,1

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @wagnet on github

Doing the following helped get rid of the metamorphs.  Thanks Peter!

Template

```
{{view Em.CollectionView itemViewClass="GS.vHomePageRestList" contentBinding="restaurantList" class="row-fluid"}}
```

View Class

```
GS.vHomePageRestList = Em.View.extend
templateName: 'tHomePageRestList'
classNames: ['span6']
```

Comment: Can you reference the specific info you got from wagnet on github?  Having a hard time following this answer and would like to try this solution as an alternative to the other answer (which works).

Comment: This was almost 2 years ago and I don't think ember even works this way anymore.  The difference was that this was using a collection view object to auto iterate over the collection and before I was manually doing a for each in handlebars.

Answer (score 3):

I've dealt with this issue by using the :first-of-type selector instead of :first-child. The one drawback is that :first-of-type is less well supported (I believe IE8 supports :first-child but not :first-of-type).